# What's the idiomatic functional way to handle processing pipeline with error logging?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, idioms

Can anyone suggest the idiomatic functional way to handle processing a pipeline with error logging. Sample imperative style (in JavaScript):

```js
const filesToProcess = ['file1.txt','file2.txt','non_existent_file.txt'];

var totalLetterCountImperative = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < filesToProcess.length; i++){
    try {
        totalLetterCountImperative += fs.readFileSync(filesToProcess[i],'utf8').length;
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("There is an error whilst processing file: " + filesToProcess[i] + ". Hence, it's skipped. Error: " + e.message);
    }
}
console.log("Total Letter Count: " + totalLetterCountImperative);
```

The below attempt works, but seems clunky and awkward. Moreover, it's not generic to all error:

```js
const filesToProcess = ['file1.txt','file2.txt','non_existent_file.txt'];

const totalLetterCount = filesToProcess
                          .filter(f => fs.existsSync(f))
                          .map(f => fs.readFileSync(f,'utf8').length)
                          .reduce((a,b) => a+b);

filesToProcess
  .filter(f => !fs.existsSync(f))
  .map(f => console.error("There is an error whilst processing file: " + f +". Hence it's skipped. Error: File doesn't exist"));

console.log("Total Letter Count: " + totalLetterCount);
```

I read about the use of `Either`. If it's indeed the idiomatic way, could someone give an example and suggest a good JavaScript library to use?

Thanks.

Comment: If you want to abandon the pipeline upon an error, use an `Either` monad, but if you just want to log the error but continue the pipeline, use a `Writer` monad. A quick google search found JS libraries for both.

Comment: Maybe you don't need a monad for this. Look into the [validation](https://github.com/folktale/data.validation) applicative. It behaves similar to `Either`, but without short circuiting and it has a vocabulary aimed towards error handling.

Answer (score 0):

In each step of your processing you produce either a "letter count" or a "console message" result. One of the simplest most direct ways to tackle this problem is to have your first pass create an heterogeneous list of these values and then do a second pass to separate those into two homogeneous lists:

```
const filesToProcess = ['file1.txt','file2.txt','non_existent_file.txt'];

var results = filesToProcess.map(function(f){
    try {
        var n = readFileSync(filesToProcess[i],'utf8').length;
        return {tag:"count", value: n};
    } catch (e) {
        var msg = "There is an error whilst processing file: " + filesToProcess[i] + ". Hence, it's skipped. Error: " + e.message);
        return {tag:"err", value:msg};
    }
})

var totalLetterCount =
    results
      .filter(r => r.tag === "count")
      .map(r => r.value)
      .reduce((a,b)=> a + b);

results
  .filter(r => t.tag == "error")
  .map(r => r.value)
  .map(msg => console.error(msg));
```

However, in my opinion, the better solution might be to take advantage of side effects and use console.error, like you are already doing in the imperative snippet. This way you don't need to mix together the cross-cutting concerns of summing things and logging errors and you will end up with something much similar than you would get if you insisted on a "purely functional" solution.

I do this kind of thing all the time when I am programming in Ocaml. It is much simpler to use side effects to append "logged" values to a queue somewhere than it would be to refactor everything to use complicated monads and/or monad transformaers.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idiomatic ES6 approach using only native modules:

```
const fs = require('fs')
const { promisify } = require('util')
const access = promisify(fs.access)
const readFile = promisify(fs.readFile)

const filesToProcess = ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt', 'non_existent_file.txt']

Promise.all(filesToProcess.map(file => access(file, fs.constants.R_OK)
  .then(() => readFile(file, 'utf8'))
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(`There is an error whilst processing file: ${file}. Hence, it's skipped. Error: ${error.message}`)

    return { length: 0 }
  })
)).then(files => {
  const totalLetterCount = files.reduce((a, b) => a.length + b.length, 0)

  console.log(`Total Letter Count: ${totalLetterCount}`)
})
```

[`util.promisify()`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) allows you to convert callback-style functions into asynchronous functions (in other words, functions that return a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises)). This allows us to avoid the use of synchronous functions, and release control of the thread when awaiting background processes, so that the thread is available to execute other tasks concurrently.

In addition, since [`fs.exists()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_exists_path_callback) is currently deprecated, I opted for the use of [`fs.access()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_access_path_mode_callback) instead.

The last change, which was very minor, was simply to supply the optional argument of `0` to [`Array#reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), so that an array of `length` 1 would still reduce properly as expected, instead of returning the first element like so:

```js
const totalLength = [{ length: 5 }].reduce((a, b) => a.length + b.length)
// since we didn't supply the optional argument, we didn't get `5` like we expected
console.log(totalLength)
```